# How to investigate cooling resp. kernel_task problem

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, temperature, cooling

On my macbook pro 2019 I'm running into this issue, where the infamous `kernel_task` starts blocking my computer after a couple of hours.

I know that many people are experiencing similar issues for many different reasons, but none of the approaches I've researched so far seem to work for me. So I really hope you can help me.

- Typically I'm working for a couple of hours using basic stuff like Zoom, Chrome and my programming IDE and everything seems fine. No lags etc. Macs Fan Control is showing the following measurements:

[image]

- Then, after 4-5 hours suddenly my whole computer gets very laggy. After checking the Activity monitor, I can see that `kernel_task` is taking up 100-300% CPU percentage.
- This `kernel_task` process seems to be a system strategy to block CPU usage and prevent further heating of the hardware that could potentially cause damage.
- This happens instantly after 4-5 hours of normal work. I do not run extra programs. The temperatures are still at ~60-65°C.
- I can stop the lagging, if I close almost all programs. But as soon as I open up some basic programs again (Zoom, Chrome) it starts lagging again

I'm now wondering on how to further investigate this issue and identify the cause of the problem:

- While Macs Fan Control is showing that the fans run at max speed, I don't feel very much air coming out of the macbook case. Maybe the fans don't work properly or are dirty?
- Can you tell me why my macbook decides to start `kernel_task` if the CPU and GPU temperature are at ~60-65°C? This doesn't seem too hot to me.

Things I've tried:

- Making sure the laptop is placed on a good stand.
- Unplugging all devices including monitors, power supply etc.
- Resetting SMC

---

**EDIT: Cleaning the fans actually solved my issue!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

65° isn't excessively hot, but it is warmer than it ought to be at idle, & would cause the fans to ramp up. Mine is at 40° right now doing not a lot. A 2019 isn't particularly old, but if you haven't blown the dust out of it in the past year, now would be a good time to do it. I do mine every 6 months & it really makes a difference to its idle temperatures.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135307/discussion-on-answer-by-tetsujin-how-to-investigate-cooling-resp-kernel-task-pr).